# Algorithm for DFA accepting any string with ending with a particular substring

Tags: algorithms, finite-automata, strings

Is there any possible general algorithm for constructing a DFA such that it accepts any string, which has a given sub-string in the suffix(end) for any given language. The algorithm should directly construct the DFA transitions, and not create an NFA first and then convert it to a DFA. In other words, the algorithm accepts the suffix as input, constructs the transitions for each state and then process the input string.

Ex 1: Language: {a,b}, Suffix- abab, Accepted Strings - bbbabab, aaabbabab
Ex 2: Language: {a,b}, suffix- babab - Accepted Strings - bababab, aababab

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Comment: The KMP string matching algorithm works this way.

Comment: Tue KMP algorithm does not provide transitions